# SQL select one row from max(date)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have been trying to get some specific but could not get it.

```
SELECT 
    idStyle, 
    idStyleDtl, 
    costPrice, 
    MAX(createDt) created, 
    idCustomer 
FROM INVOICE_DTL
GROUP BY 
    idStyle, idStyleDtl,costPrice, idCustomer
ORDER BY 
    idStyle, idCustomer
```

This is my query and

[image: Result]

This is the result.
What I expected though the highlighted part would be merged and show only one row with `created:2017-02-01 12:38:31.597` and `costPrice:11.50`(because it's the same row as `MAX(createDt)`) since they have same `idStyle`, `idStyleDtl`, and `idCustomer`. I thought `MAX(costPrice)` might be it but it just returned higher `costPrice` not the one in the same row as `MAX(createDt)`.

I want to get one entire row having `MAX(createDt)`result when there's same `idStyle`, `idStyleDtl`, and `idCustomer`.

Even small advice will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` with *window function* to make the row number by  `idStyle`, `idStyleDtl`, `idCustomer` columns and order by `createDt` DESC in subquery.

then get `rn = 1` data, which mean the max date.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        idStyle, 
        idStyleDtl, 
        costPrice, 
        createDt, 
        idCustomer,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY idStyle, idStyleDtl, idCustomer ORDER BY createDt DESC) rn
    FROM INVOICE_DTL
) t1
where rn = 1
ORDER BY 
    idStyle, idCustomer
```

Comment: Brilliant! I would have never been able to come up with this.. Just out of curiosity, is it possible to get the same result using GROUP BY?

Comment: @MinLee Yes, you can use it in subquery like `SELECT * 
FROM INVOICE_DTL t1
WHERE exists 
(
 SELECT 1
 FROM INVOICE_DTL tt
 WHERE 
  t1.idStyle = tt.idStyle 
  and t1.idStyleDtl = tt.idStyleDtl 
  and t1.idCustomer = tt.idCustomer
 GROUP BY  
  tt.idStyle,  
  tt.idStyleDtl, 
  tt.idCustomer
 HAVING MAX(tt.createDt) = t1.createDt
 ) t1
ORDER BY 
    idStyle, idCustomer`

Comment: And as you can see from the group by example while it works in your specific example, the beauty of the row_number version is you can order by multiple columns. That becomes much more involved without the row_number function.

Answer (score 0):

Often, the most efficient method is a correlated subquery:

```
select i.* 
from invoice_dtl i
where i.created_dt = (select max(i2.created_dt)
                      from invoice_dtl i2
                      where i2.idCustomer = i.idCustomer and 
                            i2.idStyle = i.idStyle and
                            i2.idStyleDtl = i.idStyleDtl
                     )
order by i.idStyle, i.idCustomer;
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `(idCustomer, idStyle, idStyleDtl, created_dt)`.